# Can I temporarily stop update notifications for one project only?

Tags: security, notifications

Is there a way I can tell Drupal not to notify me about a particular version of a module? For example, if it isn't security related and I choose not to update one module but would like to receive notifications about other modules (or future versions of the module in question)?

The Drush command from [one of the answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/77025/33636) to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26079/how-do-i-stop-drupal-checking-for-updates-for-a-specific-module) is close to what I want except if there are future security updates I would still like to know about it, just no more notifications for this particular version.

```
drush pm-updatecode --lock=module_to_ignore
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mołot. That one is similar but that solution stops checking status for good, not just for this particular version. I'd like to be notified if there is a future security update, for example.

Comment: try this from the same duplicate answer: https://www.drupal.org/project/update_advanced

you can set to ignore specific version(s) of a module, if a newer version is released you'll be notified. I'm not sure if it will only show you "security releases" but then we're cutting hairs on whether any new release is better than whats installed currently :/

Comment: Thanks -- I was actually just doing that as I noticed it after updating this. That does allow me to ignore a specific release and be notified for future releases. (It doesn't allow splitting hairs to only be notified of security updates FYI). Not sure if this qualifies as a duplicate question or not but if so, mark away. If not, add that answer @tenken and I'll accept it.

Comment: I've used the module myself (and the drush command you mentioned as well). I've answered something like this before too. But, I see the Duplicate Answer recommends a different Approved Answer, which I feel could be misleading and wasteful to someone wanting a direct answer. So I'm providing my answer below.

Comment: Don't know how to retract duplicate vote from mobile app, sorry. Will do as soon as feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Update Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/update_advanced) module:

> Extends the administrative interface for Drupal core's "Update status"
>   module. In particular, the per-project settings to ignore certain
>   projects or even specific releases, is absent in the core version of
>   the module. The "Update status advanced settings" module restores
>   these settings, and might eventually provide additional functionality
>   for the core "Update status" module.